# Problemas con diseño del input en Select2 Multiple

Tags: bootstrap-4, select2

Estoy experimentando problemas con los estilos de Select2 de tipo Multiple usando modal de Bootstrap. Al momento de Seleccionar Todo, el diseño orginal sufre alteraciones y los elementos se descolocan tal como los adjunte en la imagen...Seguí todas las recomendaciones de https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems sin embargo, aún no logro resolver el conflicto.

Intenté alguna solución eliminando uno a uno algunos estilos por si estén colisionando con Select2. No logré resolverlo.

Estoy usando AdminLte con Laravel 7 y Laravel MIX.

Mi archivo app.scss es el siguiente:

```
    // Fonts
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
    family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic');
    // My Styles
    @import 'myStyles.scss';
    // Fontawesome
    @import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
    // OverlayScrollbars
   @import '../../node_modules/overlayscrollbars/styles/overlayscrollbars.css';
   // iCheck
   @import '~icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.css';
   // AdminLTE
   @import '../../vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/dist/css/adminlte.css';
   // JTree
   @import '../../public/css/jqtree.css';
  // Datatables
  @import 
  '../../vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.css';
  @import '../../vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/plugins/datatables- 
  buttons/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css';
  @import '../../vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/plugins/datatables- 
  buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4';
  @import '../../vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/plugins/datatables- 
  searchbuilder/css/searchBuilder.bootstrap4';
 // Select2
  @import "../../vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/plugins/select2/css/select2.css";
  @import "../../vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/plugins/select2-bootstrap4-theme/select2-bootstrap4.css";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu publicación y describe el problema, solo comentas _Estoy experimentando problemas de diseño_ pero no describes cuales.

Comment: Ok. Ya lo hice mas específico. Gracias.